# Unable to clear Children of Grid Control

Tags: silverlight

I have a grid with 2 columns and 2 rows which programatically adds either a hyperlink button / a usercontrol. The way this is done is by calling a LoadData() method to clear the existing Grid and add the controls.

The problem I have is if I remove a usercontrol from the data then call the LoadData() method the code behind reloads the data correctly but the UI does not change.

It is looking like the grid.Children.Clear() is not working at all.

Can anyone help with this

thank you

Comment: This only seems to error when removing a UserControl.

Comment: Your question is not clear.
If possible can you post your code behind?

Answer (score 1):

First clear `Children`, then `RowDefinitions` (or `ColumnDefinitions`, or both):

```
gridResults.Children.Clear();
gridResults.RowDefinitions.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Interestingly swapping the order of these two lines previously worked in Silverlight 5 on win7, 
works on VM's in win8.0, win8.1  (non touch screen)

but *fails* in **win8.1 IE11.0.96 touch**, busting the **corecrl.dll** of Silverlight and shutting down IE.

Just spent a whole day on the bug and tracked it down to this...
8013150a

***see error message below:***

```
Faulting application name: **IEXPLORE.EXE**, version: 11.0.9600.17416, time stamp: 0x5452eed9
Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version: 5.1.40416.0, time stamp: 0x552f3e55
Exception code: 0x8013150a
Fault offset: 0x000475ff
Faulting process id: 0x1124
Faulting application start time: 0x01d099a89683a089
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: **c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.40416.0\coreclr.dll**
Report Id: d8a118ad-059b-11e5-8278-281878d5a598
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 


Application: **IEXPLORE.EXE**
CoreCLR Version: 5.1.40416.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET    
Runtime at IP 62F775FF (62F30000) with exit code **8013150a**.
```